# Is there a way to get msfpayload to generate a regular cmd.exe reverse tcp shell?

Tags: exploit, metasploit

It looks like msfpayload now generates a powershell-based payload when you pass it windows/reverse_tcp_shell.

Is there a way to generate a regular cmd.exe reverse shell instead?

Thanks!